# Glassfish SSE not sending events successfully to the browser EventSource (Chrome latest)

Tags: java, javascript, glassfish, server-side, server-sent-events

I have created the following class running on the server side on Glassfish:

```
@Path("events")
public class SseResource {
  @GET
@Produces(SseFeature.SERVER_SENT_EVENTS)
public EventOutput getServerSentEvents() {
    final EventOutput eventOutput = new EventOutput();
//        new Thread(new Runnable() {
//            @Override
//            public void run() {
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    // ... code that waits 1 second
                    final OutboundEvent.Builder eventBuilder
                    = new OutboundEvent.Builder();
                    eventBuilder.name("message-to-client");
                    eventBuilder.data(String.class,
                        "Hello world ");
                    final OutboundEvent event = eventBuilder.build();
                    eventOutput.write(event);


                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(
                    "Error when writing the event.", e);
            } finally {
                try {
                    eventOutput.close();
                } catch (IOException ioClose) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(
                        "Error when closing the event output.", ioClose);
                }
            }
       // }
//        }).start();
    return eventOutput;
    }
```

}

I initialized the class from the resource here:

```
resources.add(WebServicesPublic.SseResource.class);
```

And then I created an HTML page that calls the server like so:

```html
<html>
<body>
Time: <span id="foo"></span>

<br><br>
<button onclick="start()">Start</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
function start() {
    var eventSource = new EventSource("webresources/events");

    eventSource.addEventListener("message-to-client", msgClient, false);
    eventSource.onmessage = function(event) {
        document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML = event.data;
    };
}

function msgClient(event)
{
    document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML = event.data;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

However, no events ever show up in the browser.  I am running Glassfish 4.  Anybody have any idea why it doesn't work?  If I set a breakpoint in the server code, it does get hit.  However, similar breakpoints in Chrome reveal no events received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it work if you comment out `eventBuilder.name("message-to-client");` ? Without that line events will go to the default message handler, which is called "message".  (Event names *should* work, but get the default case working first.)

Also, I don't think `onmessage` syntax works, so replace that line with:

```
eventSource.addEventListener('message',function(event){
  document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML = event.data;
  },false);
```

Also, make sure you have the developer tools (network tab) open under Chrome. Your connection is lasting 10 seconds, then the server-side is closing it. Chrome will wait about 3 seconds, the reconnect. So under the network tab, after a while, you should see rows start to stack up, each 10 seconds long.  (And, if not, there should be a clue under the console.log.)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  Unfortunately, after trying that, it doesn't work.  In Chrome I can see the network responses comeing back, but I cannot actually see any data getting returned in the Response tab. Any thoughts?  Is it possible there is something I need to add to web.xml?

Comment: Sorry, I guess you'll need someone who understands Glassfish then. (If you see the connection is being made, but no data is being sent, it must be the server-side code.)